# Split string into array from StreamReader

Tags: c#, split

I'm trying to split the String "zahlen" from the StreamReader into an array "zahl".

```
StreamReader zahlen = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\nicos\Desktop\TestOrdner\Writer.txt");

string[] zahl = zahlen.Split(", ");
```

Comment: You're currently trying to split the `StreamReader` itself. You need to read from the stream.

Comment: `zahlen` is the variable you declared, you cannot split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually read the stream:

```cs
string[] zahl;
using(StreamReader zahlen = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\nicos\Desktop\TestOrdner\Writer.txt"))
{
    zahl = zahlen.ReadToEnd().Split(", ");
}
```

Or you can just use `File.ReadAllText`

```cs
string[] zahl = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\nicos\Desktop\TestOrdner\Writer.txt")
    .Split(", ");
```